# How to show different name of multiple selected options in select2.js

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select2.js, and i want to select multiple values that is working fine. But in selected values i don't want to show full content on selected text box, i want to show another content, like

```
<select id="event-users-dropdown" class="form-control" name="selectedUser[]"  multiple="multiple">
<option data-id="123456" value="1">  123456, my-name-here1 </option>
<option data-id="023456" value="2">  023456, my-name-here2 </option>
<option data-id="003456" value="3">  003456, my-name-here3 </option>
</select>
```

In this example i want to show only data-id (123456) values as selected content not '123456, my-name-here1'

Answer (score 0):

I have completed this task.

```
$("ul.select2-selection__rendered li").each(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr("title");  
        if(title){   
            title = title.substring(0, title.indexOf('-'));
            // '-' is the character till that i want to use string, ex. (123 - my name)             
            var html = '<span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>';
            $(this).html(html + title);
        }
    });
```